# Secondary index relating to Replication Factor

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am using the Secondary index for one of the column in Cassandra table.,

Say I have a **5 node cluster** (192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3, 192.168.1.4, 192.168.1.5) with the Keyspace **replication factor as '3'** and considering the following table,

```
CREATE TABLE nodestat (
    uniqueId text,
    totalCapacity int,
    physicalUsage int,
    flashMode text,
    timestamp timestamp,
    primary key (uniqueId, timestamp)) 
    with clustering order by (timestamp desc);
```

In this, I have the value of uniqueId as '**test**', which means I just have **only one partition named 'test'**.

When I perform the getEndPoints, I could see that the data resides in only 3 nodes.

```
./nodetool getendpoints keyspacename nodestat test
```

192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3

So my partition data is available in 3 nodes, I did the secondary index on one of the columns,

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX nodeIp_idx ON nodestat(flashMode)
```

So now when I perform

```
select * from nodestat where uniqueId = 'test' AND flashMode = 'yes'
```

**How many nodes will it go to collect the data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from nodestat where uniqueId = 'test' AND flashMode = 'yes'
```

Based on this query, you are using partition key along with a secondary index. Hence it will behave like a normal query based on the chosen consistency level. That is if "local_one" only one node will be enough to respond and if "local_quorum" a quorum of nodes in that dc will have to respond. Secondary index will further assist to narrow down the resultset.

Remember secondary index are local to data in every node of that cluster and hence present in all nodes of the cluster. Additional reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729254/high-availability-on-secondary-index-in-cassandra).

**In short, there is no direct correlation of Replication factor to Secondary index.**

Comment: To make it clear, All the nodes holding the replication will have the secondary index of the same data?